# How kafka retention period of a topic works?

Tags: apache-kafka

Say in a topic t1. 
The retention period is set to 2 days.
100 messages arrived in first day
100 messages arrived in second day
Total = 200 messages

Will in the third day, the whole 200 messages gets cleaned up?
Or only the first 100 messages and there will be still 100 remaining?

Answer (score 0):

The first 100 messages will be marked for deletion.

However `log.segment.bytes` and `log.segment.delete.delay.ms` also plays a role in the deletion of the logs

Consider the following scenarios :

Case 1:

`log.retention.ms = 60000,  log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000,  log.segment.bytes = 10000`

when the log segment size is breached. kafka marks the segment for deletion only when the largest timestamp passes the log.retention.ms ie. 60sec in this case.

Case 2:

If the `log.segment.bytes` is large and the log segment is not rotated till the
`log.retention.ms` is passed kafka will wait for `log.segment.delete.delay.ms` and delete the log